# "Data;" opening with Chrome when using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I am trying to run sample code to open Google on chrome from my work desktop. However it opens with "data;" in the URL.

From what I have previously seen, this can be solved by updating the Chrome Driver.exe which I have already checked and made sure is compatible so I do not know what else the issue could be. My chrome version is  77.0.3865.90 and the driver I downloaded was 77.0.3865.40

```
         var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;

var driver_chr = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();

searchTest(driver_chr);

function searchTest(driver) {
  driver.get('https//:google.ca');
  driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');

  driver.sleep(1000).then(function () {
    driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.ENTER);
  });


  driver.sleep(2000).then(function () {
    driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
      console.log(title)
      if (title === 'Google') {
        console.log('Test passed');
      } else {
        console.log('Test failed');
      }
      driver.quit();
    });
  });


}
```

Comment: "https//:google.ca" is a malformed URL.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did realize this awhile ago, but entering http://www.google.com/ fails me as well

Comment: what version of nodejs.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 10.16.3

Comment: I switched back to an older version, 8.12.0 that was working on my laptop and the  chrome driver as well but it still did not work?